# Popup does not closed event Stayopen set as False

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have use the following code snippet to define the Popup.

Code snippet[XAML]:

```
  <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0"  Height="40">       
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Text="HeaderText"                         
               FontWeight="Bold"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       <Grid Grid.Column="1">
         <Button Width="19" x:Name="FilterButton" Click="FilterButton_OnClick" Content="^"/>
         <Popup x:Name="FilterPanel" StaysOpen="False"   >
           <Border >
             <Grid>
               <TextBlock x:Name="tblTitle" Text="PopUp Header" Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
             </Grid>
           </Border>
         </Popup>
       </Grid>
    <TextBox Text="Test" Grid.Column="2"/>
  </Grid>
```

I have use the following code snippet to open the popup

Code snippet[C#]:

```
private void FilterButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this.FilterPanel.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Scenorio:

Open the popup using button click.

Press Tab.

Focus move to TextBox.

Actual Behavvior:

Popup does not close.

Expected Behavior:

Popup should be closed.

For your reference here I have attached the simple sample .Can you please any look into this and provide guidance to archive my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just manually close the Popup when TextBox gaines focus?

Comment: Thank you for your reply i can not get the Lost focus of popup or Got focus of Tetbox correctly.

Comment: Try GotKeyboardFocus event on the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange.  I took your code and pasted it in a new project window and popup closed every time.  However I remember when I wanted to create my own custom control I had a similar issue.  I know one of the things is to set StaysOpen to false.  This I see you have already done.  Another is try to setting the following when FilterPanel is initialized

```
FilterPanel.IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged +=FilterPanel_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged;

void FilterPanel_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
        { FilterPanel.IsOpen = false; } 
    }
```

As I said my code worked perfectly when I copied your code, so I couldn't test it, but the above should work.

Comment: BTW it's a good plan to "accept" the answers you get, when they do indeed answer your question - it is a way to acknowledge the response...