# popup does not close unless clicked on control and then clicked outside even if staysopen is false

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to open a popup when an item is selected from a combobox.
This part works correctly. However the popup does not close when clicked outside. 
It closes only if the button inside the popup is clicked and then clicked outside.
I have tried setting staysopen=false and have also tried giving focus to the button.
XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="cmb" ItemsSource="abcdef" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="0,0,0,232"></ComboBox>
        <Popup Name="p1" StaysOpen="False" Margin="12,85,12,159" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=cmb}">
            <Grid>
                <Button Name="btn1" Height="100" Width="100" Content="i am in a popup"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            p1.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a tooltip

Comment: I dont think tooltip will be useful since I want the popup to be opened on selectionchanged event of the combobox. Will you please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I was thinking you were more interested in it going away. Not sure why this is happening but will have a play

Comment: Try setting the focus to p1 before you open it in SelectionChanged

Comment: Hmm, I know this may be a bit of a skanky hack, but you could handle the MouseLeave event of the popup then and st p1.IsOpen to false. Ugh.

Comment: Good suggestion Kell I will give it a try.

Comment: @o_weisman tried it didnt work..{FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(windowname, p1);
            Keyboard.Focus(p1);} Gave button all the focus I could :)

Comment: You could try the suggested answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540314/popup-does-not-closed-event-stayopen-set-as-false?rq=1

Comment: Hey @Kell it worked thanks for the help, it gave some weird exception when I tried it in the example above[the code above was just the scenario I faced in my app] but it worked fine in my application. How shall I mark your comment as the expected answer?

Comment: I tried you suggestion too @o_weisman didnt get the expected behavior sorry.

Comment: Just up vote it: not to worried matey